# Do the score() and predict() methods on GaussianNB also fit the model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I hate to post this without a self contained example with code and data but I cannot reproduce my own problem consistently and I'm wondering if someone can help anyway.

I am trying to use sklearn's `GaussianNB` class. After I have trained the model using my training data, I am trying to view the score and retrieve the actual predictions. However when I run these, the score and the predictions keep changing even when I do not run `fit` in between. Here is roughly the work flow:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
classified = gnb.fit(training_data_features,training_data_results)

classified.score(test_data_features,test_data_results)
classified.predict(test_data_features)
```

Am I doing something deadly wrong? Is there a pitfall I should be aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, score and predict do not run fit.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html

What might be happening is that your dataset is too small, or too close, and most of your example are in a fuzzy area in the middle between both Gaussian Distributions, so when you run the test data, sometimes it falls in one distribution and some others in another.

What is the dataset that you are using?

Comment: Interesting.. I can see about posting my training data. It's definitely quite small: ~30 observations relative to ~10 features. I know this is very small but it was just an exercise to get the classifier working. Either way, does this mean that the prediction is probabilistic? I thought that given the same training data, a given feature vector would lead to the same prediction every time. No?

Comment: AFAIK (and I also had a look at the code) all naive Bayes variants are deterministic. You should post the data and all the code. I suspect there's a random element in your code, e.g. loading data from disk,....